# How to get JSON and show it with unordered list in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-lists

I have JSON which looks like:

```
{
    "fID": "00202020243123",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "List": ["Father", "Brother", "Cousin"]
}
```

I'm rendering this JSON element from my model, and inside of html, I can simply see the contents of the JSON. However, when I try to do it in a script, it does nothing.

What I'm trying to do is to take the List attribute and show it in unordered list in HTML.

Here is what i tried so far:

```
<script>
    $("input[name=loadmyJson]").click(function() {//on button click
        var items = [];
        var myJ = ${json}; //Json element i created in my controller
        var myVar = myJ.parseJSON();
        $.each(data, function(myVar) {
        items.push('<li>' + myVar.List + '</li>');
        });
        $('#myList').append( items.join('') );//myList is my unordered list's id.
    )};
</script>
```

EDIT: Do i need to add something for `parseJSON()` func?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `<ul> ... </ul>` tags? Otherwise if you are sure myVar contains the JSON object then it seems correct.

Comment: What's your question? Looks like a reasonable approach.  Where is it going wrong?

Comment: what is the `data` variable ?? jQuery.each takes your array / Object and runs it throw returning `arguments(key, value)` to your callback function see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8526958/887539

Comment: Actually nothing is going on, i put the <ul> tag, i guess @AndreasAL has a point, let me try the suggested answers.

Comment: actually after looking up from the Firebug, @Masiar, myJ contains json string, but in the phase of parseJSON there is sth wrong i guess, i'm not sure myVar truly has the parsed json

Comment: Have you tried using directly your myJ instead of using the parsed version of it? After all, it's a JavaScript object. You should be able to iterate over the array called List.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously look into a templating engine like [json2html](http://www.json2html.com) (which specializes in converting json to html) for jquery.  Makes life much easier than trying to write your own methods to build html from a source json object.

Note that I changed the List from an array of strings to objects instead (makes it easier to access)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://json2html.com/js/jquery.json2html-2.3-min.js"></script>

<div id='list'></div>

<script>
var json =
{
    "fID": "00202020243123",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "List": [{label:"Father"}, {label:"Brother"},{label:"Cousin"}]
};
var transform = {tag:'span',html:'.label'};

$('#list').json2html(json.List, transform);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
var myVar = myJ.parseJSON();
$.each(myVar.List, function(key, value) {
        items.push('<li>' + value + '</li>');
    });
    $('#myList').append( items.join('') );//myList is my unordered list's id.
)};
```

??

As descriped In my comment jQuery.each has the arguments `key` and `value`. the variable `this` is equal to the value (`arguments[1]`).

Same as jQuery("selector").each has the arguments `key` and `element` where the variable `this` is equal to the `element` (`arguments[1]`).

OKAY:

```
var myVar = myJ.parseJSON();
```

also has to be replaced with:

```
var myVar = jQuery.parseJSON(myJ);
```

sorry for not seeing it :)

Comment: i tried this still nothing, i guess there is sth wrong in parseJSON func

Comment: Are you sure it is a string ? Try changing the line to `var myVar = myJ;` Maybe you are working with an Object already.?

Comment: i'm sure it is string. Do i need to add something for parseJSON func? a js file or etc?

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through the `List` array that's on your object.

```
var myVar = myJ.parseJSON();
$.each(myVar.List, function(index, el) {
    items.push('<li>' + el + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: does it make any sense to use `this` instead of the second argument? normally people uses this for DOM elements in jQuery(selector).each(...

Comment: @AndreasAL - I think either would be equivalent.  I used this here so I could omit the function's parameters.  If OP were wiring up events and needing the current item in the callback, then definitely, you'd need the second parameter, since `this` will change meaning in the callback.  But for here I just figured it was a bit slimmer / cleaner

Comment: It way a matter of understanding . A said before normally people combines `this` (in jQuery context) being a DOM element we need to wrap in `$()` thats why is maybe misleading to use is when we are working with a variable. (Especially in `jQuery.each` so simmulary to `jQuery(..).each`)   :)

Comment: @AndreasAL - you're right.  this can be confusing for beginners.  I updated to use the index and element arguments to the each function.  Thanks :)

Comment: think you mean `value` ?? .. instead of `el`

Comment: @AndreasAL - I don't think so - el is what my function is taking, and el is what I'm using for the `li` - am I missing something?

Comment: Year we were both missing Object.parseJSON is `null`. it's eater JSON.parse or jQuery.parseJSON .. :).. But to our descution .. We are looping an array we can only thing we are getting an key 0,1,2,3 ... and an value : Father, Brother,...  Anyway it's works no need for wrestling just pointing out good programming matter, or even just being irritation..

Not an element elements is for `jQuery(selector).each(function(index, element) {})` where index is 0, 1, ,2, 3 and element is some kind of [DOM Element]

Comment: @AndreasAL - a for in loop over an array will return indexes.  But jQuery's $.each over an array actually returns the **elements**  Check out this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/hnQTP/

Comment: ok I'm just calling that a value not an element. But your are right it the element of the array. But again for no misleading call it value because elements is also in jQuery Objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it straight away, something like:

```
var parent = $("#myList");
$.each(myJ.parseJSON().List, function() {
    $("<li></li>").html(this).appendTo(parent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Write less code

Here's some HTML

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Then this bit of javascript

```js
$('pre').text( JSON.stringify(mJ, null, "\t") );
```

It will render your JSON just like this

```
{
    "fID": "00202020243123",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "List": [
        "Father",
        "Brother",
        "Cousin"
    ]
}
```

Finally, you can use something like [jQuery Snippet](http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/) to make it look pretty

```
$('pre').snippet('javascript');
```